# Sentiment analysis with NRC Emotion Lexicon in Python

Tags: python

How can I use a lexicon file (i.e. NRC Emotion Lexicon) for sentiment analysis in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/more-text-analysis/nrc-emotional-lexicon/

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = "NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/NRC-emotion-lexicon-wordlevel-alphabetized-v0.92.txt"
emolex_df = pd.read_csv(filepath,  names=["word", "emotion", "association"], skiprows=45, sep='\t')
emolex_df.head(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a look at this repository which provides some interfaces to the dictionary. Seems they also have a pypi

https://github.com/metalcorebear/NRCLex

```
from nrclex import NRCLex

#Instantiate text object (for best results, 'text' should be unicode).

text_object = NRCLex('text')

#Return words list.

text_object.words

#Return sentences list.

text_object.sentences

#Return affect list.

text_object.affect_list

#Return affect dictionary.

text_object.affect_dict

#Return raw emotional counts.

text_object.raw_emotion_scores

#Return highest emotions.

text_object.top_emotions

#Return affect frequencies.

text_object.affect_frequencies
```